# How to load multiple UI objects in titanium

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy

I need some help to understand what is the best way to load multiple UI objects to my window in titanium javascript.

For example if I need to load 50 views into my window the fastest way possible.

At the momento I'm using a for loop but I takes to long and the app seams to freeze while my for loop is executing.

Edit:

[image: this is what I need to due]

for each person I need to create a blue line and then I need to create a line for each medicine that this person needs to take. the problem is that I have over 30 persons, if each person takes 5 medicines that gives 150 lines plus 30 blue lines. and to create the layout it takes to long to execute.

Comment: what are you trying to layout ? can't you use a Ti.UI.ListView ?

Comment: Hy, I have updated my question. Is it faster to load data in to a Ti.UI.ListView than into a Ti.UI.scollView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily achieved using the Ti.UI.ListView component.

a listview is composed of sections, each section hold what is called items, and also each section can take optional header & footer.

please check the [docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ListView) for examples.

what you'll end up doing is for each person you'll create a section, the person's information would go in the header of each section (the header will hold labels to display the persons name & other infos), and the medicines will go in the items of each section (i.e person).

Comment: and wil this make it faster to load all components using the ListView?

Comment: it will be optimized like you wouldn't believe :) , this is the main reason for the existence of such component ... To optimize display.

Comment: once you get used to the listview, i would recommend using the model data binding as mentioned by genocsb also.

Answer (score 0):

Use Alloys Model with ListView, its the fastest way

see alloy data binding guide  [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Data_Binding)

and Appcelerator wiki ListView binding guide 
[here](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/ListView+Binding)